# Level sensor Transmitter

Tags: plc, automation, level

**I have a level sensor and transmitter(4-20mA standard) of Qidian Automation for sensing level of liquid in tank having capacity of 1000 litres. On transmitter it is displayed 0.516 when tank is half filled. How to know the unit in which transmitter is displaying this value?**

[image]

Comment: Please confirm if this is your level sensor: AliBaba QDY30A 4-20ma water liquid level sensor transmitter submersible pool water sensor transmitter HK$279.13-HK$581.51 
https://ahqidian.en.alibaba.com/product/62201803469-811272534/QDY30A_4_20ma_water_liquid_level_sensor_transmitter_submersible_pool_water_sensor_transmitter.html.

Comment: looks like 51,6% off full level

Comment: The product sheet link includes a very detailed user guide, with communication protocol and how to calculate the depth of  sensor using water surface pressure and pressure at the sensor level. Please let me know if you are using the RS485 20mA interface and more details of the interface at your mcu of computer side. Cheers.

Comment: Read the data sheet.

Comment: @tlfong01.. For now I dont't have the model number. Only I can see some values written on transmitter like, Range : 0-5m, Output : 4-20mA, PWR : DC24V, Accuracy : 0.2%FS

Comment: @Jashanjot Kaur, I am 80% sure of the following: (1) Model Number = QDY30A, (2) Communication Protocol = 20mA, (3) Wiring = 2 wires (Red = V+, Black = V-), (4) Range = 0 ~ 5 metres, (5) Power Supply = 24VDC, (6) Accuracy = 0.2% of FS (Full Scale). You need to read very carefully the user guide of the 4 features list above, and also google and/or wiki to know more details about them, / to continue, ...

Comment: It is important to understand the following: (7) What is measured is the depth/distance between water surface and the submerged sensor (I am only 80% sure). (8) I guess the setup is more or less the following: (9) The sensor is hanged by fixed length string, say 5 metres below the "normal/regular" water surface/level, (10)  So the measurement , say when water is drying out, is something like (a) now is x meters below normal/regular water level. Ah, bed time, see you tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: Two references you might find useful: (1) Current loop - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop

(2) Why use 4-20mA? - TechRentals
https://sites.google.com/a/techrentals.com.au/wiki/Home/applications/general-industrial-equipment/why-use-4-20ma. Happy learning. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01,Got model number and it is QDY60A 4-20mA liquid level transmitter. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @Jashanjot Kaur, Thank you for your clarification. So the correct model number should be: 
AliBaba QDY60A Diesel Fuel Tank Level Sensor 4-20mA Analog Oil Water Tank Level Measurement Transmitter - US$50 - US$90
https://ahqidian.en.alibaba.com/product/62200392746-811272534/QDY60A_Diesel_Fuel_Tank_Level_Sensor_4_20mA_Analog_Oil_Water_Tank_Level_Measurement_Transmitter.html . I found that this model 60A seems to have a LCD numeric display and also a LED bar chart. So you don't need to get the atmospheric pressure data and do the scary calculations. :) Good luck and cheers.

Comment: PS - In case you still have questions on the ***20mA communication protocol***, please feel free to ask me again at @tlfong01, Cheers.